# Unable to Build Code Hint Cache?

Tags: flash, air, flash-cs5, flash-cs6, flash-cs5.5

I have a very large custom class that I'm using in my Flash project (AS3, Adobe Air 3). However, I am getting this warning in the Flash Professional CS6 environment:

> *** Unable to build code hint cache. Please save the associated FLA into a different folder. There are too many files on the classpath.
>
> ---

I only have my .FLA, its related .SWF and .XML (preferences file), plus my document class .AS. My custom class is in a single folder next to the .FLA.

How do I fix the code hint cache? I use it a lot.

Comment: If code hinting is important to you you'll be a lot happier coding with FlashDevelop. Use the Flash IDE for only the graphics. I'm not sure what took me so long to realize this but I'll never go back.

Comment: The problem is, 90% of the work in Flash for us is graphics (we don't build any graphics via code, because of our animation team). Still, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of possible causes of this error, but if you're working with a file like I am (in the above question) where there is little to nothing in the directory with the .FLA, and little to nothing in the .FLA library, the solution may be as simple as **manually deleting the preferences file.**

In more detail:

Step 1: Close out of Flash Professional CS6 (or whatever version you have...this has been known to happen on CS5 and CS5.5)

Step 2: Delete the preferences file that resides in the same directory as your .FLA. The name will be something like "[project name]-app.xml" (with project name being the same name as your FLA).

Step 3: Reopen your .FLA in Flash Professional. The error icon (and problem) should be gone.

--

There are other possible solutions, depending on the nature of the problem in your case. The original clue that this might be the solution for me (which it was), as well as some other possible solutions, can be found on the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/629211).

Answer (score 1):

Quite late post, but since none of the answers worked for me; here's what I've [found](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1506250) working (tested with Adobe Animate):

> 1. Quit Adobe Flash.
> 2. Delete Code Hint Folder: *C:\Users\< user >\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CC 2014\en_US\Configuration\CodeModel*
> 3. Open Adobe Flash and create a new document. *Edit => Preferences => Code Editor*. Change *"Cache Files"* to `1500`.
> 4. Write: `import<space>` You should see the warning of: *"Building Code Hint Cache..."*. If not, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.
> 5. Wait a little and enjoy your code hinting :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but since I stumbled upon it, I'm sure someone else might too.

I was having this issue with Adobe Flash CC (2014), no code hints were working for the longest time, and I was getting a constant error stating "building code hint cache".

What fixed it for me was deleting the folder "CodeModel" located at "Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash CC 2014/en_US/Configuration/**CodeModel**.

Make sure Flash is closed when you do so, and when you re-launch flash, a new CodeModel folder will automatically be built, and if your like me, your code hinting will work like a charm.

Im not guaranteeing anything, but I have a feeling this might work with previous versions of flash as well.

**EDIT: Pressing control + spacebar seems to force the code hinting to kick in as well**